# Android: Progress Dialog Doesn't Show

Tags: android, dialog, progress

I have some data I load into the database the first time a user enters my `Activity`, and want to show a `ProgressDialog` while this data is loaded for the first time. My Activity is an `ExpandableListActivity` and I don't create the `SimpleExpandableListAdapter` or call `setListAdapter` passing my adapter until I'm sure the data is actually there. My `onCreate` looks like this:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mCategoryDbHelper = new CategoryDBHelper(this);

        // Build default categories... if not there yet
        CategoryDbBuilder builder = new CategoryDbBuilder(this);
        if (!builder.hasCategoriesInTable()) {
            showDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG_ID);
            builder.fillDbWithDefaultCategories();
            removeDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG_ID);
        }

        populate();
    }
```

I've overwritten `onCreateDialog` as such:

```
@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case PROGRESS_DIALOG_ID: {
                ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                dialog.setMessage("Loading categories for the first time. Please wait...");
                dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                return dialog;
            }       
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The `populate()` method reads the database and sets up my list adapter, then calls `setListAdapter`.

This seems like it should be simple, but it's turning out to be a huge pain. Any help would be appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AsynTask put your database loading processing in background function and in post execution display result. and there is another function to processing something until background process running here is example of asynTask

> [Android - I want to show file upload progress to the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105364/android-i-want-to-show-file-upload-progress-to-the-user/3565458#3565458)

Comment: Yeah, that's one way of doing it, however AsyncTask had a problem with me trying to make the thread sleep for a few seconds so the progress dialog would stay up for a bit and not just flash by. I ended up doing  my processing in a new thread, and killed the progress dialog in a Handler.

Answer (score 2):

Just use this simple line:

```
mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "msg to show", true);
```

You can dismiss it with:

```
mProgressDialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: Nope. No dice. Everything is fine. I got it to work by spawning another thread and doing builder.fillDbWithDefaultCategories() in the run() method.