# Android- Buffer size when recording

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

I have question regarding the buffer size. I want to record an audio and save it as WAV. Im' using `AudioRecord`. I have two questions:

First, what is the equation for the buffer size? I know that we can just use `AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(x, y, z)`. But I just want to know how it is really computed.

Secondly, how to decide that you have the right buffer size?

Since my application is all about recoding audio, I need to have a bigger buffer size, but not big enough. I want to have a biger buffer size for cases that the CPU might be distracted.

Thanks for your knowledge.
よろしくおねがいします！

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11221907/1051147

Comment: i saw this post.. i was a bit confused, but know i get it. so this is the answer to my second question. 
but what about the first question?

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#getMinBufferSize(int, int, int)

getMinBufferSize() is the minimum buffer size required for successful creation of an Audio Track object in MODE_STREAM.

Comment: also, the link is for AudioTrack