# implementing download progress bar

Tags: android, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Downloading multiple files one by one using AsyncTask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660963/downloading-multiple-files-one-by-one-using-asynctask)

I am trying to download images (probably about 20?) and then saving them into cache. 
How do I implement a download progress bar? Each image is from a individual link, if i implement a download progress bar.. would it load the download bar twenty times in my case?

this is the way i download the image and save them as cache:

```
/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */

class downloadMagazine extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading.." + "\n" + "加载中..");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    } 
/**
 * getting preview url and then load them
 * */
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_magazine, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // magazines found
                // Getting array of magazines
                mag = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MAGAZINE);

                for (int i = 0; i < mag.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = mag.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String magazineUrl = c.getString(TAG_MAGAZINE_URL);
                    //String issueName = c.getString(TAG_MAGAZINE_NAME);

                    urlList.add(magazineUrl);
                    //issueNameList.add(issueName);

                }                   
            } 
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json1 = jParser.makeHttpRequest(urlList.get(pos), "GET", param);

        // CHECKING OF JSON RESPONSE
        // Log.d("All guide: ", json.toString());

        try {
            issues = json1.getJSONArray(TAG_ISSUE);

            for (int i = 0; i < issues.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = issues.getJSONObject(i);

                String image = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);

                imageList.add(image);
                //System.out.println(imageList);
            }   

            // STOP THE LOOP
            //break;

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
        }

/**
 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
 * **/
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

/**
 *  Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
* */ 

    progressDialog.dismiss();
    getBitmap();
    buttonsCheck();
}
  }

private Bitmap getBitmap() {
if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
    cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + folderName+"/Issues/"+issueNumber);
else
    cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
if(!cacheDir.exists())
    cacheDir.mkdirs();

for (int i=0; i<=imageList.size()-1; i++)
{
    String image= imageList.get(i);
    try
    {
        String filename = String.valueOf(image.hashCode());
        Log.v("TAG FILE :", filename);
        File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);

        // Is the bitmap in our cache?
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getPath());
                // Download it
                try {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(image)
                    .openConnection().getInputStream());
                    // save bitmap to cache for later
                    writeFile(bitmap, f);
                    }    
                catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    Log.v("FILE NOT FOUND", "FILE NOT FOUND");
                }
    catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

    return null;
}

private void writeFile(Bitmap bmp, File f) {
FileOutputStream out = null;

try {
    out = new FileOutputStream(f);
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
} catch (Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (out != null)
            out.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
}
```

PS: the progress bar I meant was those that shows the % to completion

Comment: i think these threads will help you..[link1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292232/Downloading-multiple-files-using-AsyncTask-in-Andr) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660963/downloading-multiple-files-one-by-one-using-asynctask)

Answer (score 0):

1. [count the total size of all images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100737/android-download-progress),
2. show progressbar and start downloading your files,
3. while downloading update your progress,
4. only after all files are downloaded remove your bar.