# how to calculate upload/download data size in android?

Tags: java, android, mobile, broadcast

In android, how can I calculate the size of a data which I download or upload from internet?

Answer (score 1):

[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263013/java-urlconnection-how-could-i-find-out-a-files-size/263037#263037) should solve your issue. If not you need to provide some source you are using

Answer (score 1):

For uploading you might know the filesize.
for example:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile); 
int uploadSizeBytes = fileInputStream.available();
```

For download you may calculate it from loop while reading.

such as:

```
while(stream.read() != -1){
   bytesRead++ ;
}
```