# Android ProgressDialog doesn't work with mobile network

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I've developed a simple asynctask that downloads a file from a website and displays it.
There is a strange behavior:

#### When I use a Wireless connection

the ProgressDialog is correctly displayed at the beginning of download
the ProgressDialog is correctly updated from 0% to 100%
when the download is finished it disappears and the PDF file is opened.

#### When I use a 3G/Mobile connection

the ProgressDialog is correctly displayed at the beginning of download
the ProgressDialog remains to 0%
when the download is finished it disappears and the PDF file is correctly opened.
What could be the problem? (I'm using Android 2.3.7)
Thank you!

```
public class TamTam extends Activity {
    public ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(TamTam.this);
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        new DownloadFileAsync().execute("http://www.*******.com/file.pdf");
    }

    class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        String fileName;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
            int count;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
                URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();

                conexion.connect();

                int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();

                fileName="output.pdf";
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + "/" + fileName));

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                count = 0;
                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) > 0) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress((int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return null;

        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    showPdf(fileName);
        }
    }
    public void showPdf(String fileName)
    {
       ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Code tip: you make it hard on yourself with the publish progress. Have your AsyncTask use an `Integer` for the progress updates that way you avoid the `String` conversion/`Integer` parsing. Also to make your code clearer, make `onPostExecute()` work with `Void` (capital V) instead of `String`.

Comment: Have you verified that "lengthOfFile" is meaningful in the 3G case?

Comment: Almost certainly this is not related to the ProgressDialog class itself, but rather the different network behaviors on if/how you measure progress. I would focus on the type of status/progress information you get back from the 3G network.

Comment: Thank you very much! You were right: the problem was with lengthOfFile. I have resolved like this: HttpURLConnection conexion = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); conexion.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
to find the length of file

Comment: If you have found a solution, please post your answer and "accept" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mike said, the problem was with this line:

```
int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
```

The problem was that the content-length header hadn't been provided by the server.
Using a HEAD request, i got the server to reply with the correct content-length field which otherwise was empty. To specify the request method I had to use HttpURLConnection, instead of URLConnection.

So I've changed this block

```
URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
conexion.connect();
int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
```

with this

```
HttpURLConnection conexion2 = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conexion2.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
int lenghtOfFile = conexion2.getContentLength();

URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
conexion.setDoOutput(true);
conexion.connect();
```

Sources:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

[Java URLConnection : how can I find out the size of a web file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263013/java-urlconnection-how-could-i-find-out-a-files-size)