# How to get progress of downloading a file with audioinputstream java

Tags: java, progress-bar

I am new to downloading a file with java and sorry if its a dumb question but I've searched for 2 days and couldn't get a solution. I am using JPanel within an applet and I want to show the download progress in a progressBar.(maybe download is not the correct word it is more likely an initialization)

What i want is to show a download process of a wav file from an URL.I don't mean to show the reading process(i will let the user know the file is being processed later.)  i just want to get the progress of *ais=AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);*

i tried to use *ProgressMonitorInputStream* but this doesn't work for me, because i want to add the progress bar to my JFrame. I have looked for *swingWorker* but the usage of it does not give me the progress i want.

Here is my read function. I am also changing the wav format according to my needs.

```
    public void readFile() {

    byte[] data = null;
    AudioInputStream ais = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/Samples/AFsp/M1F1-Alaw-AFsp.wav");
        ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);


        AudioFormat format = ais.getFormat();
        numberOfChannels = format.getChannels();



        AudioFormat TargetFormat = new AudioFormat(format.getSampleRate(), 16, numberOfChannels, true, false);
        AudioInputStream desiredFormatStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(TargetFormat,ais);
        data = new byte[4];
        int totalSampleCount = ais.available()/(format.getSampleSizeInBits()/8);


        audio = new double[totalSampleCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < totalSampleCount-1; i=i+2) {
            desiredFormatStream.read(data);

                if(!TargetFormat.isBigEndian()){
                    audio[i] = ((short) (((data[1] & 0xFF) << 8) + (data[0] & 0xFF))) / ((double) MAX_16_BIT);
                    audio[i+1] = ((short) (((data[3] & 0xFF) << 8) + (data[2] & 0xFF))) / ((double) MAX_16_BIT);
                }
                else {
                    audio[i] = ((short) (((data[0] & 0xFF) << 8) + (data[1] & 0xFF))) / ((double) MAX_16_BIT);
                    audio[i+1] = ((short) (((data[2] & 0xFF) << 8) + (data[3] & 0xFF))) / ((double) MAX_16_BIT);
                }

        }

        StdAudio.open(TargetFormat);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not read " + filename);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to open a [`URLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) on your already present `URL`-object and query the `Content-Length` http-header field. Use the [`getContentLength()`-method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength()) to do so.

> **NOTE** if you're downloading large files, an `int` might not be big enough to hold the  content length. Therefor,
>   [`getContentLengthLong()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLengthLong%28%29) should be prefered. This method is
>   **available since Java 7**.

This will hold the length of the file in bytes. When you're reading via [`AudioInputStream.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29), this method will return the actual amount of bytes read each time.

**Pseudo-code**

```
long totalLength = con.getContentLengthLong();
while still reading{
  long totalBytesRead += in.read();
  print "Process: "+(totalBytesRead * 100 / totalLength);
}
```

**See also**:

- [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/263013/717341) with examples on using the content-length
- Article on [using unbuffered](http://codeisland.org/2012/working-unbuffered-streams/) streams