# Unable to open PDF File in Android App Webview

Tags: codeigniter, android-webview

I have generated pdf file using mpdf library in Codeigniter. I'm able to open pdf file in all browsers using the link e.g(http:www.example.com/uploads/pdf/test.pdf) but the link doesn't work on android web view.

Comment: did you have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411095/android-webview-download-and-view-pdf-xls-or-doc-files?rq=1 ?

Comment: i need just click the link internal url and view the pdf file on webview app. i don't know how to resolve the problem.