# Get size of file before downloading over HTTP

Tags: java, http, download, http-headers

I'm downloading a file over the internet using HTTP and I would like to make a progress bar. How do I determine the size of the file I'm going to download, in bytes. I'm using an `HttpURLConnection` in Java, and I tried getting the `Content-Length` property in it, and it returned 529, even though the size of the file to be downloaded is ~200MB.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a bug on their end.

Comment: Take a look at this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263013/java-urlconnection-how-can-i-find-out-the-size-of-a-web-file).

Comment: Look into Apache Commons IO

Comment: @qualebs we've been using nio for most of our needs, and want to avoid a new library.